# Populate bootstrap dropdown using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

How can I populate a bootstrap dropdown from codebehind? Right now I am trying this:

```
    HtmlGenericControl li;

    for (int x = 3; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "myItemClass");
        li.InnerText = "Item " + x;

        myList.Controls.Add(li);
    }
```

This does add the items but it completely loses the bootstrap design on the `<li>`-items. Also, how do I know which value is `DataTextField` and which is `DataValueField`?

Dropdown html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="myList" runat="server">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are following the example at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns - only you are just adding `<li>` items, whereas they are using `<li><a/></li>`

Comment: I had a hunch that this was the problem, but my questions still stands since I dont know how to add `<li><a/></li>` items

Comment: probably something like `li.Children.Add(new GenericControl("a"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be easier for you to add them using a literal, like this:

Dropdown.aspx:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="myList" runat="server">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" id="litDropDown"></asp:Literal>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Dropdown.aspx.cs:

```
for (int x=3; x<10;x++)
{
    string liText = "";

    liText = liText + "<li role=\"presentation\">";
    liText = liText + "<a role=\"menuitem\" tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"#\">";
    liText = liText + "Item " + x;
    liText = liText + "</a></li>";

    litDropDown.Text = litDropDown.Text + liText;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! PS: If I want to add `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. How can I do this using this method?

Comment: @iQue - Can you provide an example of what you are trying to acheive?